# Can not access android /data folder?

Tags: android

```
  try {
     Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
     Process pcs = rt.exec("ls -l /data");
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pcs
           .getInputStream()));
     String line = null;
     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        Log.e("line","line="+line);
     }
     br.close();
     pcs.waitFor();
     int ret = pcs.exitValue();
     Log.e("ret","ret="+ret);
  } catch (Exception e) {
     Log.e("Exception", "Exception", e);
  }
```

only print "ret=0",How to print the correct path?

Answer (score 4):

Android protects it's internal directories.  You can only access your directory under `/data/data/your_package`.  I believe that the normal user does not have `Read` privileges for the `/data` directory on a normal device.

Answer (score 1):

data folder is inaccessible on a device except by system processes. You cannot access data folder of a unrooted phone through adb. You can access data folder of emulator or rooted phones.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing it with your own app, and not by spawning another process (e.g. Runtime.exec())

```
File dataDir = new File("/data");

    String[] files = dataDir.list();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < files.length ; i++ ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "File: "+files[i]);
    }
```

Also, I'd look at the different read permissions, maybe there's another way to get to the data you're looking for via ContentProviders.

Comment: This will not help - a process spawned by an app runs as the same userid as the app and so has the same permissions.  Unless of course you are invoking a setuid process, like an "su" root shim.

Answer (score -2):

If you'll want to access /data folder not from java code, but from your PC console - you can use a `adb shell` command. it has no restrictions.

remember to have an emulator running, or connect your phone via USB before running that

Comment: adb shell does not give you root access without having a rooted device, it it will however work on the emulator